# How to solve open file heap error

Tags: c, file-io, stream, malloc

I am trying to put some stream from one file in a buffer then save it in a long stream and finally send it to a server but after creating a file open I have an error for heap and memory space. I am using IDE compiler which is used for Openpicus board.

This is my code snippet:

```
pFile = fopen("Nini.jpg", "rb");
if (pFile==NULL)
{
    fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);
}

fclose( pFile);
```

There is a heap problem when I try to read an Image.

Is there any solution for this? Otherwise how can I solve this problem with malloc?

Comment: The error is not in the code you provided, and must be elsewhere. Give us more information and please post the *exact* error you're receiving.

Comment: yes the exact error is related to compiler .

Comment: this is error :`*                     Total program memory used (bytes):        0x298b3  (170163) 64%
c:\program files (x86)\microchip\mplab c30\bin\bin\..\bin/pic30-coff-ld.exe Error: A heap is required, but has not been specified
`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has absolutely nothing to do with your file opening/closing code. [A quick Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=a%20heap%20is%20required%20but%20not%20specified) (which took me all of 5 seconds, mind you) yields [the following potential solution](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m600435-print.aspx) (quoted from original):

> - go to project properties (File->project properties)
> - under categories go to pic30-ld
> - find the heap option in the window to the right

Comment: Yes I have found this site in less than 5 seconds and I tried to solve the problem but I had the same problem again.

Comment: @HOsseiNSA Ok, but your post is misleading and is not going to find you an answer. The problem has nothing to do with that section of code and possibly nothing to do with the code at all.

Comment: I found my problem is not in the whole my code and it is just in first line when it tries to read an .jpg file. the problem is related to compiler.